# What is the smarter solution to retrieve the number of pages of this created PDF file?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

this is one of my first time that I use iText and I have a dount about the correctness of my solution.

Into an application I create a PDF composed by many pages (some hundreds) and I save it on a file, doing something like this:

```
String result = outputPath + "\\" + pdfName + ".pdf";
com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document(com.itextpdf.text.PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);

PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(result));

.......................................................
.......................................................
.......................................................
```

So, essentially, at the end I will have my **.pdf** file into a directory. It works fine.

Now I have to count the page number into this file.

Searching some documentation I found this link (that I think is the official documentation): http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf

Specifically it say:

> You can query a PdfReader instance to get the number of pages in the
>   document

So in my code I done something like this:

```
try {
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(result);
    System.out.println("NUMERO PAGINE PDF CONCATENAZIONE FATTURE: " + pdfReader.getNumberOfPages());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
```

It works fine but I am asking if, in my case (I have the **PdfCopy copy** on which I add the **PdfImportedPage** page object) I have some smarter soluton different to create a new **PdfReader** object that read the final pdf file. Or is it the best solution?

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have finished creating a PDF, you can create a `PdfReader` instance and ask that `reader` object for the total number of pages. That is true.

However:

it seems that you are not creating a PDF from scratch. Instead you are using `PdfCopy` to concatenate many different documents. Allow me to complete your code:

```
PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader(path1);
PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(path2);
Document document = new Document();
PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
document.open();
copy.addDocument(reader1);
copy.addDocument(reader2);
document.close();
reader1.close();
reader2.close();
```

In your code snippet, you omitted the fact that you are already creating `PdfReader` objects, hence you do not need to create a new `PdfReader` instance to calculate the total number of pages in the final result. Instead you can just add up the number of pages from the `reader` objects you added to `PdfCopy`:

```
int total = reader1.getNumberOfPages() + reader2.getNumberOfPages();
```

Just make sure you calculate the total number of pages *before* you close the `PdfReader` instances.